# Rendering a component in JSX vs via function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When using React, what is the difference (and when should each method be applied) when rendering a component?

Does this impact the component lifecycle in any way? Or impact how hooks are run in the component?

Method 1:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  ...
  function getComponent() {
    return <Component />
  }
  render() {
   return this.getComponent()
  }
}
```

Method 2:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  ...
  render() {
   return <Component />
  }
}
```

Comment: `method 1 was invalid`. inside the class direct function initialise not working

Comment: @xadm - What's not invalid? You may have been seeing an edit. prasanth was correct that "Method 1" *was* invalid prior to the edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(**Note:** The OP has now changed the question, it used to have `return {this.getComponent()}` in Method 1.)

`render` in Method 1 is incorrect *(well, it was before the edit)*, it should be:

```
render() {
  return this.getComponent() // No {} wrapper
}
```

You need the `{}` within a JSX context, but you're not in a JSX context there. For instance, if you wanted to wrap what `this.getComponent` returned in a `div`, you'd use the JSX expression to define the `div`'s children within the JSX defining the `div`:

```
render() {
  return <div>{this.getComponent()}</div>
}
```

With the `{}` sorted out, whether you use Method 1 or Method 2 is up to you. If you have substantial parts of the render that you want to move into their own functions, that's fine. For instance:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.getHeader()}
            {this.getBody()}
            {this.getFooter()}
        </div>
    );
}
```

...although I think I'd probably argue at that point that without a good counter-argument, the header, body, and footer should probably be components (perhaps function components). But the occasional helper function call like that is fine.

> Does this impact the component lifecycle in anyway?

No. It's just a function call within `render`.

Answer (score 4):

There is no real difference between both. I'd personally use only one `render()` method as much as possible, then when the method gets too big, extract parts of it into their own method.

Answer (score 4):

I have found this great [article](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/dont-call-a-react-function-component) by Kent C. Dodds. An extract of the article is:

> React doesn't know the difference between us calling a function in our JSX and inlining it. So it cannot associate anything to the `Counter` function, because it's not being rendered like a component.
>
> This is why you need to use JSX (or React.createElement) when rendering components rather than simply calling the function. That way, any hooks that are used can be registered with the instance of the component that React creates.

With this in mind, it sounds like it's better to use JSX when rendering a component that uses hooks.